# what is wrong with python my python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

1.I dont konw  why “if QUEUE_HTMLNODE.qsize()>0” can be true,because i think the "if mytuple[0].qsize()>0" will never be true so the QUEUE_HTMLNODE.qsize() will never biger than zero,but the code result some times print the"jump   my_tuple_list".so I am Puzzled.

2.Thank you for everyone help me.The full code is here:

```
#encoding=utf-8
import threading,time  
import Queue
import pdb
QUEUE_HTMLNODE=Queue.Queue()
QUEUE_URLNODE=Queue.Queue()
TOTAL_COUNT=0
stop_flag=0
EXIT_FLAG=0
my_tuple_list=[]
QUEUE_URLNODE.put('way')
def single_thread(mytuple,QUEUE_HTMLNODE):
    global TOTAL_COUNT
    global stop_flag
    global EXIT_FLAG
    while stop_flag<15:
        if mytuple[0].qsize()>0:
            html_node="lll"
            QUEUE_HTMLNODE.put(html_node)
            TOTAL_COUNT+=1
        else:
            stop_flag+=1
            time.sleep(5)    
    EXIT_FLAG += 1
for i in xrange(10):
    my_tuple_list.append((Queue.Queue(),str(i)))
threads_list=[]
for i in xrange(10):
    threads_list.append(threading.Thread(target=single_thread,args=(my_tuple_list[i],QUEUE_HTMLNODE)))
for i in threads_list:
    i.setDaemon(True)
    i.start()
while (True):
    for i in my_tuple_list:
        if QUEUE_URLNODE.qsize()>0:
            node = QUEUE_URLNODE.get()
            i[0].put(node)          
            print "in the my_tuple_list 中 "

    if QUEUE_HTMLNODE.qsize()>0:
        print "jump  my_tuple_list"
        print QUEUE_HTMLNODE.qsize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because you are using multiple threads, though no idea why you are using that.

To put it simply, here is the steps that is occuring -

1. You have created a thread which calls the function `single_thread` with the values for the queue in `my_tuple_list` (each element) and `QUEUE_HTMLNODE` .
2. You are then starting the thread, for first pass its fine and `mytuple[0].qsize()` is `0` so nothing is added to `HTMLNODE` queue.
3. But simultaneously, in the main thread , you are checking if `QUERYNODE` is 0 , if it isn't you are adding elements into the queue in `my_tuple_list` this is the same queues that you sent into the threads.
4. Now, after waking up from the sleep for 5 seconds, it checks if `my_tuple[0]` is still empty (`qsize` is equal to zero) , but this time it is not empty, because in main thread you put an entry inside the queue in `Step 3` (above) , and since these are just threads, they share the global namespace , where the queues and lists are defined (and python's function calls are pass by reference.
5. So this time it puts entries into the `QUEUE_HTMLNODE` , so the next time you go check the `QUEUE_HTMLNODE` its `qsize` would be greater than 0 , leading to what you observe.

A simple example to showcase your behavior -

```
>>> import threading
>>> import time
>>> def func(l):
...     i = 0
...     while i < 15:
...             l.append(i)
...             i += 1
...             time.sleep(1)
>>> def foo(t):
...     t.start()
...     i = 20
...     while i > 0:
...             print(l)
...             i -= 1
...             time.sleep(0.5)
>>> l = []
>>> t = threading.Thread(target=func, args = (l,))
>>> foo(t)
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```